# ng-repeat table,how to add some input(text) for one of rows,like the picture:

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[this table is created by ng-repeat,I want to add a row input for a row,just one,not all rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCQVw.png)

[this is my html,how to add,thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Rely.png)

Comment: Please, present a minimal and reproducible example in the question.

Comment: you can use the variables available inside the scope of ng-repeat, and provide the input box for one of the elements in the array [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat]

Comment: In ng-repeat add two rows per iteration, one with text and another with input boxes with display:none property and one some event just remove display property for that particular row of text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

To add input element to any one row and not all the rows, you could use the $index by checking the rowIndex value. 
for ex:

```
ng-if = "$index == 2" or ng-show="$index==2"
```